# Connecting to my Visual Studio Online API returns HTTP 302

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-devops

I'm trying to connect to my VSTS build 2.0 api through Node to create a new build definition. I'm getting HTTP 302 , which is an redirect. I'm not sure why this happening, I was able to submit same request, with same URL through SOAP UI without any issue. Below is the code snippet.

```
 var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
            var client = new Client();
            var accessToken = 'MY ACCESS TOKEN';
            var args = {
                data: JSON.stringify(configJSON),
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Accept": "application/json"}
                ,auth: {
                    'bearer': accessToken
                }
            };

            client.post("https://firstname.lastname.visualstudio.com/SampleApp/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=2.0", args, function (data, response) {
                console.log(response.statusCode);
            }).on('error', function (err) {
                console.log('something went wrong on the request', err);
            });
```

Comment: Hi, the reason is that the authentication is failed, I updated my answer, you can check it.

Comment: What's the result after specify Authorization in headers?

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that the authentication is failed, so it redirects to the login page, that's why you get the 302 response code.

I modify the code to add Authorization to header and remove auth parameter, after that it works fine.

```
var args = {
        data: JSON.stringify(configJSON),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
        }
        //, auth: {
        //    "Bearer":accessToken
        //}
    };
```

On the other hand, I suggest that you can create build definition through vsts-node-api or PowerShell.

For VSTS-node-api, there is createDefinition function in [BuildApi](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-node-api/blob/master/api/BuildApi.ts) (xxx), [there](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-node-api) is a sample about how to use it.

For PowerShell, you can use Invoke-RestMethod to call REST API, [there](http://blog.devmatter.com/calling-vsts-apis-with-powershell/) are some samples in this article.